# Building a maven jar for TestNG automation project

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I have a Selenium and TestNG automation project which I am building using Maven.
I have created the entire project using the Maven folder structure and have used Excel sheet for fetching the Test Data.

I want to create a runnable jar of the project so that I can run it from another system.I am able to successfully create a jar file with all dependencies and with the main class in MANIFEST.MF.

However, when i run the jar file, I get IO Exception.
I believe that the whole issue is with the Test data sheet not getting packaged within the jar.
The test data sheet appears under test-classes folder and not within the packaged jar.

Can anyone kindly suggest a solution or a workaround for this?
I have attached the screenshot of my Project Folder Structure [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLa8P.jpg) and a snippet of my pom.xml [pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMOXZ.jpg)

Comment: Writing an additional api which reads the spreadsheet and packaged with jar will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move Main class at src/main/java, and add:

   ```
   <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <mainClass>com.ee.testScrips.Main</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
           <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
           </descriptorRefs>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. If you want to create a jar containing test classes :

   ```
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.6</version>
               <executions>
                 <execution>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>test-jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                 </execution>
               </executions>
             </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Hi @question_maven_com..Thanks for your answer..i have placed my java class having main method at src/main/java and have included the maven-jar-plugin in my pom.xml. But when i create the jar file and try to run it, i get an error saying "no main manifest attribute".